# dev_appserver.py crash in debug mode

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

All developers in my team are experiencing the same issue with the new app engine dev server, which hard crashes when debugging via eclipse. The server runs perfectly in "Run Mode", but in "Debug Mode", it starts up fine, but as soon as you hit it with a request, it hard crashes with nothing logged in the console.

Anyone else getting this issue? And any tips on fixing it?

Comment: I'm using 'Debug As' -> 'Pydev: Google App Run' and it works fine for me (Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 / PyDev 3.9.1.201501081637 / GAE 1.9.17). Could you provide exact steps / version info?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1  / PyDev 3.8.0.201409251235. I will try upgrading my PyDev - that could be it. I'll let you know if it fixes it. Thanks

Comment: Updated PyDev. Restarted Eclipse. Same problem.

Comment: Same problem for me too, same steps, 'Debug As' -> 'Pydev Google App Run'. Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 / PyDev 3.9.1.201501081637 / GAE 1.9.17 / Java 8 Update 31